# Updating a built-in function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, packages, options

I am using Mathematica 10.2 and would like to know how to update a built-in function.
For example, I am trying to utilise the `ScalingFunctions` and `MultiaxisArrangement` options within `ListLinePlot`, but they are not recognised by Mathematica when I pass them to `ListLinePlot`. See below.

**Example 1**

```
ListLinePlot[{Range[10], Prime[Range[10]]}, MultiaxisArrangement -> All]

Out[1] = Unknown option MultiaxisArrangement->All in ListLinePlot[{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}},MultiaxisArrangement->All]. >>
```

**Example 2**

```
ListLinePlot[{1, 5, 10, 35, 60, 75, 140}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
Out[2] = Unknown option ScalingFunctions -> "Log" in ListLinePlot[{1, 5, 10, 35, 60, 75, 140}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]. >>
```

How do I update the function so that it includes the above-mentioned options?
I don't have licenses for the later versions (>10), so upgrading Mathematica is not an option for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think it's possible to update single functions like ListLinePlot[] in Mathematica. Usually core/built-in functions like that are updated during a upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: At least as a workaround for the ScalingFunctions -> "Log", why not just rescale the data manually? Or use ListLogLogPlot[] and Joined->True.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the built-ins (that's any software company's main tool to sell updates after all), but you can use [the `MultipleAxesListPlot` resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesListPlot/) that accomplishes the same end goal:

```
ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesListPlot"][{Range[10], Prime[Range[10]]}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: result of MultipleAxesListPlot]

---

It will also work with the ScalingFunction option:

```
ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesListPlot"][
  {Range[10], Prime[Range[10]]}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
]
```

[image: log plot]

Alternatively, you can always scale the data by hand as mentioned in comments.

Comment: It should be noted that resource functions are only supported in 11.3+ as far as I know, Also, I would be surprised if `MultipleAxesListPlot` didn't rely on the `ScalingFunctions` mechanism of the normal `ListPlot`

Comment: @LukasLang You make a good point about the ScalingFunctions. Regarding their support, their code is available in the source notebook posted on the repository page, so perhaps their automatic loading might not be possible, but one could copy and paste the code.